# Выборка записей до ключевой при ее существовании или полная выборка без нее

Tags: mysql

Как выбрать записи до ключевой при ее существовании а если ее нет сделать полную выборку

```
SELECT rf_con, urlima, date_l, user_mes 
FROM device_ima 
WHERE 
    rf_con=103 
and date(date_l)>=STR_TO_DATE('2016-12-07','%Y-%m-%d') 
and date(date_l)<=STR_TO_DATE('2016-12-09','%Y-%m-%d')
and idima < (SELECT idima 
             FROM device_ima 
             WHERE rf_con=103 
               AND CAST(user_mes AS DECIMAL( 12, 0 )) >= 10 
             ORDER BY idima DESC 
             limit 1
            )
```

Мой запрос выбирает только если есть ключевая запись а если ее нет не чего не выдает.

Comment: вместо подзапроса напиши объединение таблицы с самой собой левым джоином. и в условиях выборки будет либо тот же самый знак "меньше" как сейчас, либо равенство null (если записей нет).

Comment: `and idima < COALESCE((your subquery), max_for_idima_datatype)`

Comment: @Akina  Если в условии указать < тогда при NULL – COALESCE выводится не максимальное значение idima а предыдущее.
А если указать <= тогда при NOT NULL – COALESCE ключевое значение попадает в выборку.
Но вариант мне нравиться.

Comment: max_for_idima_**datatype**

Comment: @Akina Извиняюсь я не понимаю что именно вы хотите этим сказать. max_for_idima_datatype  это максимальное значение столбца idima ? Или это что-то другое

Comment: Это максимальное, ё моё, значение для **ТИПА ДАННЫХ** этого столбца. не имеющее никакого отношения к тому, что хранится в таблице. Если поле, скажем, `UNSIGNED INTEGER`, то это будет 4294967295.

Comment: @Akina Ааа понял. Все работает. Большое вам спасибо.